# Kendo ui Disable column when add new record

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, radio-button, kendo-grid

How do I achieve this, I want to disable radio button on **Status** Column only when Add New Record and checked on **YES**.

[image]

I don't know which part of script should I give. But here I provide some of it.

My KendoGrid Script

```
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataBound: setColor,
        height:400,
        sortable: true,

        columns: [ 
            { field: "segmentActive", title:"STATUS", width: "120px", editor: RadioSegmentActive, 
              template: data => data.segmentActive == "y" ? "Yes" : "No" }, // <-- displaying Yes/No insted of y/n

            { field: "marketSegmentName", title:"SEGMENT NAME", width: "120px" },

            { field: "publicPrice", title:"PUBLIC PRICE", width: "120px", editor: RadioPublicPrice,
              template: data => data.publicPrice == "y" ? "Yes" : "No"},

            { field: "isHouseUse", title:"HOUSE USE", width: "120px", editor: RadioHouseUse,
              template: data => data.isHouseUse == "y" ? "Yes" : "No"},

            { command: ["edit",{ name: "destroy", text: "De-active" }], title: "&nbsp;", width: "120px" },
        ],
        editable: "inline",
        ...........
```

My RadioSegmentActive function

```
function RadioSegmentActive(container, options) {
var guid = kendo.guid();

    $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio3" name="segmentActive" type="radio" value="y" >').appendTo(container);
    $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio3">YES</label>').appendTo(container);  //YES
    $('<br>').appendTo(container); 
    $('<input class="k-radio" id="radio4" name="segmentActive" type="radio" value="n" >').appendTo(container);
    $('<label class="k-radio-label" for="radio4">NO</label>').appendTo(container);  //NO        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "Checked on Yes", but you can do that by handling the [edit event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit) of the grid:

```
editable: "inline",
edit: function(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) { // We are adding
        // if ($("#radio3").prop("checked")) {  // Check some field...
        $("#radio3").attr('checked', true);  // Set yes radio button
        $('input[name=segmentActive]').attr("disabled",true);  // Disable radio buttons
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: it means when user "Add New Record" radio button on Status column is disabled and by default checked in "YES"

Comment: It works for disabled radio button, but at the same time I want the default value checked on "YES". Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need your help again. It worked fine but i need to change **attr** to **prop**  `$("#radio3").prop('checked', true);` and it will display what I want. But it not fetch the value **y**  when I save it. It will insert null.

Comment: You may be running into issues with your template and binding. I have always avoided modifying the DOM dynamically when using Kendo because it composes them at grid creation time and then hooks up all the binding and other events. Try using a [kendo template](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview). Otherwise, you might be able to add a command to your function that updates the model. See [here](http://blog.codebeastie.com/kendo-grid-javascript-data-manipulation/).